# Подключения к интернету во время игры

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor, unity3d-android, ads

Если у человека отключен интернет, при заходе в игру, а после он включает его, как мне поставить загрузку рекламы? т.е. мне нужно проводить инициализацию или проверять готова ли реклама? т.е. пройдет ли инициализация без интернета при старте?

P.S. Использую 5.2.4 т.к. выше не могу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот вопрос нужно уточнять в документации той площадки, чью рекламу вы собираетесь использовать. В том случае, если автоматический функционал они в своём плагине не реализовали, то можно просто установить какой-то интервал, например - в минуту. 
И при запуске плагина рекламы запускать корутину, которая будет пытаться подключиться. В случае удачного подключения - корутина заканчивается, если неудачно - ждёт минуту и пытается подключиться снова.

При это добавить стоит и дополнительную проверку на тот случай, если сначала интернет был, но потом он выключился. При каждом неудачном запросе рекламы проверять запущена ли сейчас корутина подключения, если нет - запускать. В итоге таким образом реклама вернётся, как только опять появится интернет.

Comment: писал я о самом Unity Ads, но дело в том что я и инициализацию провожу каждых 10 секунд, и проверяю готова ли реклама (т.к. она постоянно загружается) но помогает только перезапуск приложения

Comment: @k0vpack, в таком случае вам нужен плагин UnityAds 2. там это ошибка была исправлена, если верить словам разработчиков. Сам плагин можно скачать из asset store https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/unity-ads-66123 . В более поздних версиях Unity он интегрируется автоматически, вам же придётся качать отдельно.